# Wordpress Hook text style "color" not working

Tags: css, wordpress

I tried using  to style WP Hooks on a mini theme am building but "color" attribute didn't work.

```
    <span style="color: #C40000; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size:26px; padding: 5px; line-height: 1; text-decoration: underline; -moz-text-decoration-color: #C40000; text-decoration-color: #C40000;">

    <?php echo the_category(''); ?>
    </span>
```

Comment: works for me - https://jsfiddle.net/7gc1jehp/. is the span in an anchor? if so, try put the colour on the anchor

Comment: currently seeing it as static text. It would work if text is static, but when its dynamic (wp hook) it won't and it use to so i want to know if there is any update that's change the way it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your css file class with your category styles

```
.category-style{
    color: #C40000;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:26px;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-decoration: underline;
    -moz-text-decoration-color: #C40000;
         text-decoration-color: #C40000;
}
```

next create filter, you can place it in functions.php

```
<?php 

    add_filter( 'the_category','category_style', 10, 3 );

    function category_style( $thelist, $separator, $parents ){

        $class_to_add = 'category-style';

        return str_replace( '<a href="', '<a class="' . $class_to_add . '" href="', $thelist );
    }

?>
```

and last one display category in your file.

```
<?php echo the_category(''); ?>
```